# Lotus Notes - How to have formula in input translation in a field to auto-populate another field?

Tags: lotus-notes

There are 2 fields in my Lotus Notes application, `ContactName` and `CompanyName`.

`CompanyName` have an input translation formula which will check the data in `ContactName` to refer to a view, which will then give `CompanyName` it's data.

```
Company:= @Unique(@DbLookup("";@DbName;"Visitor List 1";@Text(ContactName);2));

@If(CompanyName = ""; @If(ContactName != ""; Company[1];"");@Text(companyname))
```

However, it has the problem of not showing up automatically unless if I click another field, only then the data will appear. My plan is for the data to show up quickly once I finished filling in `ContactName`

To test, I tried moving the formula above from `CompanyName` to `ContactName` to see if reaction can trigger faster. It does, kinda. If I simply copy and paste formula as it is the `CompanyName` data will just override the `ContactName` data.

I modified it to:

```
Company:= @Unique(@DbLookup("";@DbName;"Visitor List 1";@Text(ContactName);2));

@If(CompanyName = ""; @Text(CompanyName = @If(ContactName != ""; Company[1];""));@Text(companyname))
```

But that just immediately give `ContactName` the value 0. What else can I do to modify the formula?

Comment: `ContactName` is a list of values?

Comment: It's a field in a form. But I have a view that compiles it's data from all documents in the database which is then referred to using the formula. Same applies to `CompanyName` too. How it functions is when I enter a `ContactName`, `CompanyName` will then search the view I created to find the last saved document with the matching `ContactName`, copy the `CompanyName` data and paste it into the current `CompanyName` field.

Answer (score 1):

I have had your problem sometimes and depend of the type of field, you can configure it to refresh the form when it changes or force it to do the same by `lotuscript`.

**When your field is a list**

[image]

When you have a list field, you can set it like the picture.

**When your field is a textbox**

That is your case I think, and you can force a refresh like when you use <kbd>F9</kbd> with `lotuscript`, so the field has some event where you can develop you solution, and one of them is `Exiting`, you can try this to force a full refresh of the form when an user exits from the field:

```
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument

Set uidoc = ws.Currentdocument

Call uidoc.Refresh
Call uidoc.RefreshHideFormulas
Call uidoc.Reload
```

Comment: The options settings helps a lot. But there seems to be an issue of if I want to change the data of `CompanyName` it will automatically changes back to the value it gives me from its auto search. Say for example Choosing `ContactName` [Lee] gives me `CompanyName` [Z]. If I want to change the `CompanyName` to [ZI] the field will just revert back to [Z] for me. Is there an option to prevent that?

Comment: Two ways: config the field like `computed when composed` or saving the first value in other field when you save the form.